# What are the new unique-id's for CUDA streams and contexts useful for?

Tags: cuda, uniqueidentifier, cuda-streams, cuda-context, cuda-driver

CUDA 12 introduces two new API calls, `cuStreamGetId()` and `cuCtxGetId()` which return "unique ID"s associated with a stream or a context respectively. I'm struggling to understand why this is useful, or how this would be used. Are the handles for streams and contexts not unique? i.e. does CUDA create copies of `CUstream_st` and `CUctx_st` structures with the same values, or which describe the same entities? If it does - under what circumstances?

Comment: Maybe one could get a unique identfier for a thread's ‘cudaStreamPerThread‘ to distinguish it from another thread‘s stream

Comment: @AbatorAbetor: Well, the thread's own identifier, such as it is, plus the stream handle, constitute a unique identifier of that stream... (and quite possibly even just the handle itself is sufficient).

Comment: I can see it being useful for deterministic ordering, e.g. in profiler output. Plus, as I understand it, the streams are mapped onto hardware queues, e.g. [32 in Kepler](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-zib/frontdoor/deliver/index/docId/5036/file/ZR-14-19.pdf). It would be interesting to see if the stream ID provides the mapping and if so, can we create false serialization by issuing work only on streams whose ID has the same modulo 32.

Comment: My guess would be that these are the IDs one also sees in nSight Systems, so it might be useful to identify streams (contexts) when there are many.

Comment: @paleonix: I don't know... we already have stream name assignment for that purpose, don't we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stream handle does not uniquely identify an active stream. Consider the following sequence:

```
cudaStream_t s, s2;
cudaStreamCreate(&s);
slow_kernel<<<grid, block, 0, s>>>(args);
cudaStreamDestroy(s);   // no synchronization - the kernel is still running!
cudaStreamCreate(&s2);  // almost certainly s2 == s
fast_kernel<<<grid, block, 0, s2>>>(args);
cudaStreamDestroy(s2);
```

In the example above, you'll almost certainly get `s2 == s` even though the `slow_kernel` is still running - it's even possible that `fast_kernel` finishes before `slow_kernel`.

On top of that there's an issue with special handles like default stream or per-thread default stream. Thread ids can be reused by the OS, too (albeit not as aggressively).

One place where uniquely identifying a stream is crucial is stream-ordered resource management (like cudaMallocAsync).

Assigning a stream name doesn't solve the issue, because the party interested in establishing stream identity/equality doesn't necessarily own the stream and assigning a name would constitute a breach of contract.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `CUstream_st` reuse. But - what guarantee do I have that `cuStreamGetId()` for `s` and for `s2` won't also be the same?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__STREAM.html#group__CUDA__STREAM_1g5dafd2b6f48caeb13d5110a7f21e60e3

The documentation says:

Returns in streamId the unique Id which is associated with the given stream handle. *The Id is unique for the life of the program. *